# Iron Webscraper connects to host but doesn't scrape?

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I'm trying to use [Iron Webscraper](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/webscraper/examples/c-sharp-web-scraper/) to get a list of names on a website. The element itself is just an `<article>`element with a list in it. Nothing special there.

But given the code sample they have on their website, after running it on the site I want to scrape from, nothing happens.

Below are the two methods that have to be implemented when extending the WebScraper class. I have checked that `Init()` produces the correct URL before passing it to `this.Request()`:

```
public override void Init()
{
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(baseUrl);
    if (originType != OriginType.None)
    {
        string language = originType.GetEnumDescription();
        if (!language.Equals(null))
        {
            url.Append("/").Append(language);
            if (genderType != GenderType.None)
            {
                string gender = genderType.GetEnumDescription();
                if (!gender.Equals(null))
                {
                    url.Append("/").Append(gender);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Gender came back null in OriginItemCardScraper");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Language came back null in OriginItemCardScraper");
        }
    }
    baseType = url.ToString().After("com/");
    this.LoggingLevel = LogLevel.All;
    this.Request(url.ToString(), Parse);
}
```

But the code never reaches the following method:

```
public override void Parse(Response response)
{
    foreach (var title_link in response.Css($@"<article class="" data-category=""{baseType}>"))
    {
        string strTitle = title_link.TextContentClean;
        Scrape(new ScrapedData() { { "Title", strTitle } });
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

So that leads me to believe that I never get a response.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the reason why is because I am not using `StartAsync()`. As soon as I did that, the thing worked. Not sure why `Start()` doesn't work.